# Use the Action Mailer of Redmine to send e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to send email from a local server (to "admin@admin.com" ):
My problem is how to use the Action Mailer of Redmine into my plugin because when I use an other Action Mailer, I have to configure both of them(it is not good).

```
@nouvelle_remarque = Remarque.new
@nouvelle_remarque = Remarque.create(:project_id => @project.id ,
                                   :version_id => params[:version] ,
                                   :numero => params[:numero] ,
                                   :phase => params[:phase] )
if @nouvelle_remarque.save
    flash[:notice] ="ok"
    # ....... code of sending a new mail
  else
    flash[:error] ="ko"
  end
```

thanks for help :-)